# Publishing and installing private windows mobile apps

Tags: windows-8.1

I've seen similar posts but most are for consulting companies who work with clients so the situation is slightly different for us.

We have an onsite developer preparing to design a Windows Metro App to interface with our system. This app will be 100% unique for our business and would serve no public person any purpose. We will be designing this app for our sales team (8-10 users) to use out in the field so as you can tell it is only associated with our business. I believe people have been referring to this as a LOB app. I've seen posts about publishing to the windows store or using a "side-loading" process but one is meant for consumers and the other is meant for enterprise publishing which is way overkill for us.

Can someone please assist me with our options as a small business to publish private apps and deploy them to our own equipment?

I'm open to using the Store but obviously wouldn't want just anyone to be able to download & install our app.

Comment: Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj657971.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for you would be to hide the app in the store. Unfortunately this is only available for Windows 10 apps, not for Windows 8.1!

Is Windows 10 an option for you, maybe? In the developer dashboard you can choose to hide the app but you can access it with a direct link. [image]